# Is it possible to POST one specific item from a List using Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my Spring Boot app i have the following `RequestMapping`:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String get(Model model) {
    List<CustomItem> items = itemService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("items", items);
    return "test";
}
```

I'm displaying these items in a simple HTML table (one row for one item).

I'd like a add a button to each row that submits only the corresponding `CustomItem` to an endpoint something like this:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
public String post(CustomItem item) {
    // doing something with item
    return "redirect:/test";
}
```

What i've tried is to create a separate `form` for each row:

```
<table>
 <tr th:each="item, stat : ${items}">
  <td>
   <form th:object="${items[__${stat.index}__]}" th:action="@{/test}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="${items[__${stat.index}__].someField}">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

But i'm receiving the following error when navigating to the page:

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'items[0]'
>   available as request attribute

I've tried the following as well:

```
<table>
 <tr th:each="item, stat : ${items}">
  <td>
   <form th:object="${item}" th:action="@{/test}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{someField}">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

In this case the error is the following:

> Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'item'
>   available as request attribute

I cannot figure out what's wrong with my approach, so i'd really appreciate any advice.

**EDIT:**

As [@StefanEmanuelsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860473/) suggested i've tried omitting the `th:object` attribute:

```
<table>
 <tr th:each="item, stat : ${items}">
  <td>
   <form th:action="@{/test}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="${items[__${stat.index}__].someField}">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This way the page loads just fine, but on submitting the form the value of `someField` in the received(?) `CustomItem` in the controller is `null`.

Comment: The thymeleaf docs says:

> "Values for th:object attributes in form tags must be variable expressions (${...}) specifying only the name of a model attribute, without property navigation. This means that an expression like ${seedStarter} is valid, but ${seedStarter.data} would not be."

I guess that your code qualifies as property navigation since you are using the iteration variable as th:object? I would try using th:field="${item.someField}" instead of th:object.

Comment: @StefanEmanuelsson thanks for your reply, please check the edit at the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this problem by simply using `th:value` and `name` attributes instead of `th:field`:

```
<table>
 <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
  <td>
   <form th:action="@{/test}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:value="${item.someField}" name="someField">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Instantiate item in the controller and set to the model:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String get(Model model) {
    List<CustomItem> items = itemService.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("items", items);
    model.addAttribute("item", new CustomItem());
    return "test";
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
        <tr th:each="i : ${items}">
            <form th:action="@{/test}" method="post" th:object="${item}">

                <td th:text="${i.id}" />
                <td th:text="${i.name}" />
            <td><input type="hidden" th:value="${i.id}" name="id" />
                <input type="hidden" th:value="${i.someField}" name="someField" />
                <button type="submit" name="action" value="remove">OK</button></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And create a method in controller to handle the item:

```
@PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(@ModelAttribute CustomItem item,HttpServletRequest request) {
        doStuff(item);
    }
```